# How to debug WCF SSL issues?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have a WCF application which was working perfectly fine until recently when we introduced some SSL related settings and certificate requirements into our application. As soon as we turned out the SSL following started happening:

1. When I launch the service using my Visual studio it launches fine without any errors and With Https in the URL
2. As soon as I click on WCF URL to see the WSDL, it fails with SSL connection error.

Browser does not provide any more information on this. I have also installed WCF Trace utility and it traces most of the errors correctly BUT not this one(probably because it does launch the application fine but fails when we try to launch the WSDL)

Any suggestions on a good tool that can help me debug SSL errors any better?

Comment: What's the exact error you get? Troubleshooting options: 1) Enable System.Net trace: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2012/11/05/use-system-net-trace-and-ssl-alert-protocol-to-tshoot-ssl-connection-issue.aspx - 2) Use Wireshark or similar to sniff the SSL handshake: http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I found very very helpful while working with WCF in general is using Idiagnostic module. It does not relate to any specific SSL related issues but it helps debug issues in general